# Remove Input Individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I wish to add numbered inputs in their name (already successfully did), but also erase them with a click of a button if empty (couldn't). With this code, ALL the search class inputs are erased. I only want the empty ones REMOVED. Here is my try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// contains the counter for elements added
window.__buttonClickCounter = 1;

// Keep reference to container
var c = document.getElementById('inputs');

// Click handler that appends to the contents of the container
var clickhandler = function () {
    c.innerHTML = c.innerHTML + "<input class='search' style='margin-bottom:4px;' type='search'         name='word" + window.__buttonClickCounter + "'/>";
    window.__buttonClickCounter++;

    $('#removebtn').click(function () {
        $('.search').remove();
    });
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: when the removebtn is clicked how you will know which inputs has to be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it using jquery as follows

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $('#addbtn').click(function(){
        $('#inputs').append('<input class="search" style="margin-bottom:4px;" type="search"         name="' + counter++ + '"/>')
    });

    $('#removebtn').click(function(){
        $('.search').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if(!$this.val()){
                $this.remove()
            }
        });    
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DSh8v/)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the non-empty ones from the jQuery object before calling `.remove()` like this (thus removing only the empty ones):

```
$('#removebtn').click(function () {
     $('.search').filter(function() {return !this.value}).remove();
});
```

If the `.filter()` callback returns `true`, then the item is kept.  If it returns `false`, then the value is removed from the resulting jQuery object.  So, this starts with all `.search` objects, then keeps only the ones where `!this.value` is `true` which means it keeps the ones where `this.value` is falsey (e.g. empty) so only the empty ones get `.remove()` called on them.

---

Or, a little more reusable way:

```
// Reusable jQuery method for filtering out non-empty input values
// Also filters out items that don't have a `.value` property
$.fn.filterNonEmpty = function() {
    return this.filter((function() {return !this.value});
};

// now use this new jQuery method
$('#removebtn').click(function () {
    $('.search').filterNonEmpty().remove();
});
```